# JPA: ManyToMany issue - Spring Boot Project

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I want to establish many-to-many relation between two table. One is called `User` and the other is `Tag`.
My goal is to add previously created `Tag` lists to newly created `User` objects. `Tag` must be added to the database first, and then merged with `User` after selecting from existing ones.

How can I solve this problem? Where am I doing wrong? Any advice?

Thank you.

All my codes are as follows.

**Filename = Demo2Application.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo2Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private TagService tagService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {


        //Scenario: Tag list is already created.
        Tag tag1 = new Tag("strong", true); //id = 1
        Tag tag2 = new Tag("weak", true);   //id = 2
        Tag tag3 = new Tag("nice", true);   //id = 3
        Tag tag4 = new Tag("clever", true); //id = 4
        tagService.save(tag1);
        tagService.save(tag2);
        tagService.save(tag3);
        tagService.save(tag4);


        //Scenario: Defining a new user.
        User user1 = new User("foo", "foo@gmail.com");


        //Scenario: Appropriate predefined tags are being added to the new user object.
        user1.addTag(tagService.findById(1));
        user1.addTag(tagService.findById(4));


        //Scenario: Registering a User object to the database.
        userService.save(user1);


    }
}
```

**Filename = entity/Model.java**

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updatedAt;

   // standard constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

**Filename = entity/User.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Model {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_tag",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    //

    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.add(tag);
    }


    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
```

**Filename = entity/Tag.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag extends Model {

    @Column(name = "tag_name")
    private String tagName;

    @Column(name = "tag_active")
    private boolean tagActive;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_tag",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

   // standard constructors, getters, and setters
```

**Repositories = TagRepository, UserRepository**

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}


public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, Long> {
}
```

**Filename = service/UserService.java**

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User findById(long id) {
        Optional<User> result = userRepository.findById(id);
        return result.orElse(null);
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

**Filename = service/TagService.java**

```java
@Service
public class TagService {

    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TagService(TagRepository tagRepository) {
        this.tagRepository = tagRepository;
    }

    public Tag findById(long id) {
        Optional<Tag> result = tagRepository.findById(id);
        return result.orElse(null);
    }

    public void save(Tag tag) {
        tagRepository.save(tag);
    }

}
```

**Filename = resources/application.properties**

```
server.port=7070
## Database (PostgreSQL + Hikari + JPA)
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1200000
#
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=1234
#
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
## Database ##
```

Comment: Now your tag object was not associated with your user object while fetching it from db..?

Comment: How so? What should I do?

Comment: I'm asking you whether tag list is coming from user object??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean because I'm really new, but what I'm trying to do is bidirectional access. The tag list will already be added to the database and will not be mapped to any User. Merge will be done as new User objects arrive.

I hope I can answer.

Comment: You need to configure join table annotation at one only side. Please remove any one of this.

Comment: I tried both of them but problem is still continue.

Comment: consider reading this: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many